# Загрузка неперсонализированной рекламы

Tags: android, admob, gdpr

Как написано в [руководстве](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#forward_consent_to_the_google_mobile_ads_sdk), чтобы сдлеать рекламу неперсонализированнай для пользоватлей Евросоюза, нужно использовать следующий код:

```
val extras = Bundle()
    extras.putString("npa", "1")

val request = AdRequest.Builder()
    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, extras)
    .build()
```

**Вопрос:** Таким образом, чтобы мне загрузить неперсонализированную рекламу мне нужно использовать нижеприведённый код?:

```
myAdBanner.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

или нужно передавать изменённую переменную `request` в каждую метод загрузки рекламы (даже в те, которые в других активити) и, соответственно, использовать такой код:

```
myAdBanner.loadAd(request)
```

> **Аргумены:**
>
> 1. [Здесь](https://youtu.be/jJuhnFiHAb0) автор, в комментарих, пишет, что можно
>      использовать вариант номер 1, то есть, не пердавать полученную
>      переменную `request` в `.loadAd()`
> 2. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904184/how-to-show-ads-in-other-activities-based-on-the-user-choice-from-the-gdpr-conse/56061017#56061017), в ответах, написно, что нужно использовать вариант номер 2 и
>      передавать `request` в каждый `.loadAd()`
> 3. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371241/is-valid-add-npa-0-in-bundle-extras-for-personalized-ads-in-consent-sdk-admob), как я понимаю, склоняются тоже к варианту номер 2.

Так какой, получается, вариант правильный?

Comment: однозначно использовать request созданный с extras

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом вы создаёте объект Request, который настроен на то, чтобы показывать не персонализированную рекламу, то есть это надо передавать во все методы loadAd